# Mupdf is free or licence?

Tags: android, mupdf

I am developing an application, in which I am using `mupdf` library.

Do I require any license (for `mupdf` library), so I can upload my app to `Google Play Store`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a library licence advice (which can be googled about), not for solving a specific code issue.

Answer (score 4):

The excerpt from the [official site](http://mupdf.com/):

> **License**
>
> MuPDF is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
>   the terms of the [Affero GNU General Public
>   License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html) as published by
>   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at
>   your option) any later version.
>        MuPDF is Copyright 2006-2015 Artifex Software, Inc.
>
> **For commercial licensing please contact sales@artifex.com.**

Comment: I am develop application for client. So, for that I have to licence or not?

Comment: Please note that I am not a lawyer. If you want to distribute/sell an application that uses this library and earn money from it you need to contact them via email `sales@artifex.com`.